# Why is the Process.GetProcessesByName() always null?

Tags: c#

I try to use program to check the process if it exists.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ServProInfo
{
    class Program
    {
       public static int IfProcessExist(string processName)
        {
            try
            {
                Process[] targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
                int proLen = targetProcess.Length;
                if (proLen == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The process does NOT exist or has exited...");
                    return 0;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The process status is: Running");
                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\r\n" + ex.Source);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string type = args[0];
            string name = args[1];
            switch (type)
            {
                case "p":
                    IfProcessExist(name);
                    break;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

However, the Process[] targetProcess is alway null, even when I set processName as an exist process's name.

How could I correct the program?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you run the program? Like: The parameters you're passing to the program?

Comment: I guess the process was not found. Is your process a 32 bit process, and the other process 64 bit? That's the most common failure mode.

Comment: If you try to get the process with the extension, remove it, e.g try to get "svchost" and not "svchost.exe"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try the following: (works fine for me)

```
Process[] targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(processName));
```

Comment: So are you saying that you need to remove the extension in order to use `GetProcessesByName`?

Comment: I think the answer to that is yes. If I do Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer") I get any instances of windows explorer coming back.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] p1 = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process pro in p1)
{
    if ((pro.ProcessName.ToUpper().Contains("Application Nanme")
    {
        //U r Operations
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't going to work. You specify ToUpper, then don't give an uppercase string to match